# JQuery attribute (empty) value selector, not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, forms

The elements & the code.

HTML

```
<input value="" name="data[Filter][address]" type="text" />
<input value="" name="data[Filter][client]" type="text" />
<input value="" name="data[Filter][tenant]" type="text" />
<input value="" name="data[Filter][contract_end_date]" type="text" />
```

Javascript

```
console.log($("[name*='data\\[Filter\\]'][value!='']").serialize());
```

The problem: even if they are all empty, they are serialized.
Why?

Comment: Well your elements do not have an attribute value with a value of "" so they will be selected.

Comment: mmmm.. tried it now, no change. (edited, thanks)

Comment: Well when the value changes, the attribute does not change.  http://jsfiddle.net/9Jg86/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking at the value attribute. You can filter off of the value property instead:

http://jsfiddle.net/Y2P6w/

```
var $filledElems = $("[name*='data\\[Filter\\]']").filter(function () {
    return $.trim(this.value).length;
});
```

Comment: And the value attribute is not the place to look at, because... ?

Comment: The value attribute doesn't change when someone types in the field, or when you assign a new value using `.val()` or `.value`. It's the value _property_ that changes. Also, as epascarello just commented, your elements don't even have a value attribute.

Answer (score 1):

The point is when the input tag gets inserted to the page, no matter it is in the page load or in your dynamic JavaScript codes, if it has the value attribute your selector query would use it or if you change your input's value using `setAttribute` in JavaScript or `.attr()` in jQuery, their value attribute actually gets changed, but if you change it with `.value` in JavaScript or `.val()` in jQuery or simply change the value in the page as a textbox, the attribute won't change, so you better not use value attributes in your selectors, because they are not reliable, an instead use `$("[name*='data\\[Filter\\]']")` and filter it as @JasonP has pointed out.